# Forensic search of a iMac 27", i7 2.8 quad

Tags: macos, file-search

I am being asked (forced), in a legal battle, to search for files I never downloaded. My attacker is not insisting that I hire someone else so I want to do it myself. It is very expensive and I'm sure they will weasel out of paying the bill. I want to do a great job so they cannot criticize the effort. What software can I use that will allow me to limit the date range, search normally hidden files and be widely acceptable?

Cheap is important and Mac compatible is required.

Any ideas? 
Thanks. 
2009 IMac 27" 4-core i7 2.93 Ghz 
Plus 3 drives and a macbook pro.

Comment: It is doubtful that they will trust you to do a thorough job, if you are party to a legal action. You may need to hire a third party, or at least have your legal counsel verify the search.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question.

Comment: This is not a legal question. The real world context does not redefine it as a point of law any more than saying 'my boss asked me to find xyz on my computer' is a question about my engineering job. However it does request a software suggestion, which I gather is inappropriate, so I will restate the question.

Answer (score 1):

If they want evidence - most especially 'proof of a negative', which is nigh-on impossible to prove -  then make them do the work & provide 'positive proof'.

[I'm not a lawyer, but frankly, this is simple common-sense. Innocent until proven guilty, as the adage goes]

Comment: Unfortunately, in civil suits innocent until proven guilty is NOT the standard. It is 'preponderance of evidence.